# Why are my setInterval() functions not working as I intend them too?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I wrote this simple code, that should repeatedly open google.com, and close it.

However, the code only appears to run once. How can I fix this code?

*I apologize for this newbie mistake. I am new to JavaScript programming.*

---

Here is my code:

```
<html> 
  
<body> 
  
<p>Click the button to eat your RAM</p> 
  
<button onclick="start()"> 
Start Opening Site
</button> 
  


<script> 

function OpenNewTab() { 
window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank"); 
}

function CloseNewTab() {
openedWindow.close();
}


function start() {
setInterval(OpenNewTab(), 200);
setInterval(CloseNewTab(), 300);
}



    

</script> 
  
</body> 
  
</html>
```

Comment: no parenthesis just `setInterval(OpenNewTab, 200)` also functions are usually written in camel case

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write

```
setInterval(CloseNewTab, 300);
```